# Google Cloud Firestore - How to display a part of an entire document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Sometimes, we don't want to display to the end user the entire document. For example - let's say we have `users` collection and each `user` has an `email` property. The last thing we want to do is to display the users' emails to each other.

So in RTDB, [it was simple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data), since it's not structured as collection/document.

On Cloud Firestore, it's not as simple as RTDB. You can't filter the document to your needs, as [stated in their docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules):

> When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security rules are not filters—queries are all or nothing.

So I thought about 2 alternatives:

#### 1. Split the `user` collection into `public` and `private` sub-collections.

- **Pros** - You can have different rules to `public` and `private`. In other words - you can prevent other users to view `private` doc of a different user.
- **Cons** - When you just want to get the entire document of the user, you'll have to make 2 reads instead of once, and then merge their response (assuming you don't get any errors).

#### 2. Handle filtration of the user in the back-end (using Admin SDK).

- **Pros** - This way, I only read one document, and I don't have to split my document into objects.
- **Cons** - I haven't found a way so I could subscribe to the desired cloud function (I want to listen for changes).

I know that there's no one-way-go to achieve certain goals, but I would like to know if there's a more conventional approach of achieving what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option is the most common, but if it doesn't work for your case, then don't use it.

Bear in mind that with your #2 option, you add complexity on both the client and the server.  And you lose client side caching, which might save you a lot in terms of performance and billing.